# Not able to understand correctly, how Event Hub consumer group working

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

**Requirement** I want to process event data (same data) from multiple consumers parallel

[image]

What I understand from documentation to process same data form event hub we need to create multiple consumer groups.

Consumer groups enable multiple consuming applications to each have a separate view of the event stream, and to read the stream independently at its own pace and with its own offsets.

Message Retention 1,
Partition count 3

[image]

**Problem: I'm not getting data form log1 consumer group**, Instead log1 When I tried $Default and log2 consumer group I was getting data in parallel.

Can anyone help me understand this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features) , your understanding is correct. I tried to create my event hub as same as yours to reproduce your issue.

[image]

[image]

And I start 2 EPH via java code to monitor Log1 and log2 separately.

Then I send 10 messages to event hub to observe the 2 EPH console log.

[image]

It seems that I can receiver messages from both of them,however the order is messy. I guess the your issue is `delay`.

---

***Update Answer:***

Per my knowledge, `delay` in Azure event hub may be affected by many aspects. Maybe network , internal internal mechanisms. However ,Azure event hub ensure that your data is not lost during effective storage time.

If you need to ensure real time data , you could use [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) which is used for building real-time data pipelines and streaming apps.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you spent on this question. Thank you so much.

Comment: @PankajRawat Any progress about your issue?I also want to know.

Comment: I think It was delay issue. I don't know the reason for a delay.